# Awk script to extract a portion of input file

Tags: text-processing, awk

How do I write a `awk` script that scans the input file for "start" and finds the line containing "next" and displays the following line? Something like this:

```
    [user]$ cat test.txt
    start
    next
    This line should print
    Ignore this


    [user]$ display.awk test.txt
    This line should print

    [user]$ cat test1.txt
    Ignore this
    next
    Ignore this
    start
    Ignore this
    next
    This line should print
    Ignore this
    next
    Too late so ignore this too
    start
    Ignore this too

    [user]$ display.awk test1.txt
    This line should print
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {start="no"; nextline="no"}; nextline=="yes" {print; exit}; (start=="yes" && /^next$/) {nextline="yes"}; /^start$/ {start="yes"}' test.txt
```

And as a standalone script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {start="no"; nextline="no"}
nextline=="yes" {print; exit}
(start=="yes" && /^next$/) {nextline="yes"}
/^start$/ {start="yes"}
```

### Explanation

This might make more sense reading the first dot point first, then reading the rest in reverse.

- `BEGIN {start="no"; nextline="no"}`: to start, set both variables to `"no"` (i.e. we haven't found them yet). N.B. `next` is a reserved word, so I used `nextline`.
- `nextline=="yes" {print; exit}`: when we have found `next` from a previous line, print the line then exit.
- `(start=="yes" && /^next$/) {nextline="yes"}`: after finding the `start`, if we also find `next` in a line, then set `nextline` to `"yes"`
- `/^start$/ {start="yes"}`: if we find start, set `start` to `"yes"`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Replace `/^start$/` with /^Start from here$/

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/start/,${        # in this range
$!{                       # if not the last line                         
/next/{                   # and if line matches "next"
n                         # read in the next line
p                         # print pattern space
q                         # quit
}
}
}' infile
```

With `gnu sed`:

```
sed -n '/start/,${$!{/next/{n;p;q}}}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

this should also work

```
awk 'BEGIN {l1=0} /^start$/{l1=1} /^next$/ && l1==1 {l2=NR+1} NR==l2 {print;l1=0}' test.txt
```

it uses the record number NR to print the record after the first next encountered after a start line.